# CodeIgniter Controller breaks when calling parent constructor

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have the following code in helloworld.php:

```
<?php

class Helloworld extends CI_Controller {

public function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
}

public function index()
{
    $this->load->model("helloworld_model");
    $data["result"] = $this->Helloworld_model->getData();
    $data["page_title"] = "CI Helloworld appis";
    $this->load->view("helloworld_view", $data);
}

}

?>
```

The code stops executing after calling the parent constructor, without giving absolutely any error messages. Nothing appears in /var/log/apache2/error.log either. If I echo something before constructor call, it is echoed. If I type gibberish before the constructor call, a proper error message is printed. Why is this happening?

The site is running on Ubuntu server 12.04 with Code Igniter 2.1.4. and PHP 5.3.

Other files are helloworld_model.php:

```
<?php

class Helloworld_model extends CI_Model {

public function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->database();
}

public function getData()
{
    $query = $this->db->get("data");

    if ($query->num_rows() > 0)
    {
        return $query->row_array();
    }
    else
    {
        show_error("Database is empty");
    }
}

}

?>
```

And helloworld_view.php:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title><?php echo $page_title ?></title>
</head>

<body>
    <?php foreach($result as $row): ?>
        <h3><?php echo $row["title"]?></h3>
        <p><?php echo $row["text"]?></p>
        <br />
    <?php endforeach ?>

</body>
</html>
```

As far as I understand, the Controller constructor is what gets called absolutely first, so I don't think the rest of the files matter at this stage(?).

Comment: Please show the rest of the code. What happens when you do `parent::__construct(); echo 'Hello';`? Also do you have error reporting enabled and `display_errors` on?

Comment: Nothing gets printed after the parent constructor call. display_errors is on, and all other errors are printed normally. One moment, I'll post rest of my code.

Comment: What happens when you remove the constructor all together? I noticed your closing your php tags at the bottom of the page, try removing the closing php tag and any whitespace from the bottom of the controller.

Comment: @Jeemusu Absolutely nothing will appear on the page if I remove the constructor and nothing gets printed in other functions either. Removing the closing tags results in a parse error. Removing white space does nothing.

Comment: I started doing this following a really crappy tutorial with lots of mistakes and for an older version of CI, but I tried to fix it along the way to work with 2.1.4. I think I'm just going to start over with a more up to date tutorial since I just don't understand what can be wrong in this.

Comment: Well, you don't need the closing tags. I find that they tend to cause problems in Codeigniter.

Answer (score 3):

I had same problem that was resolved by changing `'dbdriver' => 'mysqli'` to `'dbdriver' => 'mysql'` in you `config/database.php`. Also make sure your database connection parameters are correct.

Comment: for php56, i change from mysql to mysqli.

Comment: I changed it from `'mysql'` to `'mysqli'` and issue is fixed.

Answer (score 1):

My guess, and I would have to see your configs to be sure, is that there is a problem in the initialization of your `Loader`. Most commonly this has to do with the automatically loaded libraries, and sometimes it has to do with a bad database configuration. My first suggestion would be to try to get something working using the default configs. If that works, then you have a good starting point.

Comment: Indeed, when I started fresh, I encountered the same problem, but now it happens specifically only when I load the database inside a model. I think I am following instructions to the letter, and again it doesn't help that it doesn't give any error messages from this and only from this..

Comment: Well I still don't know what caused the original problem, but this db-related problem was solved by installing php5-mysql package.